# howto install usb_cam on ROS Groovy

Tags: usb-cam, ros-groovy, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I would like to install usb_cam from BOSCH on Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I already managed it to install and make it work on a different laptop on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, but I can't remember the exact steps.

What I tried is: I created and setup a workspace in my home, I downloaded the source files and wanted to compile it. There were no errors during the compilation, but apparently no binaries were created, as it also said during compilation "ROS_NOBUILD in package ...".

Could please someone describe the process step by step?

Edit 1:
In the meanwhile I installed almost all the ros packages, and then it worked. However I don't know which package(s) was/were missing for the compilation of the usb_cam.

Edit 2:
A different approach, as proposed by @joq in his answer, is to install usb_cam from the ros-shadow-fixed repository. I managed to install it on my machine, however, strangely at first apt was looking for several 32 bit dependencies and denied to install, but a couple of minutes and several tries later it was installed. Before you ask, I did apt-get update after adding the repository.
Now I just have to find out, how can I make a camera node and a launch file, but it is a different question.

Edit 3:
the binary usb_cam_node file is missing from the installation.

Edit 4:
with the newest ros-groovy-usb-cam v.0.1.2 driver (from the ros-shadow-fixed repository) it is working great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62052/howto-install-usb_cam-on-ros-groovy/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not just install the binaries?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-usb-cam
```

**UPDATE**: that package is not yet in the main repository, I found it in shadow-fixed. It should be released soon.

To get it right now, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` to `ros-shadow-fixed`, like this:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu precise main
```

**UPDATE2**: as @ZoltanS discovered, that shadow-fixed package is not installing the `usb_cam_node` (or much of anything else). Apparently, it is being converted to catkin, but the conversion is not yet complete.

If you want to build from source, the [Fuerte version (0.4.2)](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/bosch-ros-pkg/code/tags/stacks/bosch_drivers/bosch_drivers-0.4.2/usb_cam/) is still using rosbuild. Building that on Groovy with rosmake will probably work.

This driver is not yet released to Groovy, but I will notify the maintainer anyway, to make sure he knows about this problem.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-05**:
In which repository is it? I can't find it on the net. There is a ros-fuerte-usb-cam package, but as the name says it is for fuerte and not for groovy. Did you found the package for groovy?

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-06**:
Thanks for the instructions. Unfortunately, it seems to only work for i386, it requires a lot of i386 dependency packages, which can not be installed on my 64bit machine.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-06**:
It installs fine on my 64-bit Precise machine. Please edit your original question, adding what you did and what errors you saw.

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-06**:
Now it also installed it on my computer. I don't know what the problem was.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-06**:
Good to hear. I recommend restoring your APT sources to the regular ROS repo now that the driver is installed.

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-06**:
thanks joq! I am missing the usb_cam_node which is normally in the bin library if usb_cam is compiled from the source. I am afraid I don't know how to use the package without the usb_cam_node. Do you have this file in your package?

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2013-05-06**:
The missing install files have been fixed in usb_cam 0.1.2 which was just pushed. It should be making its way through the build farm shortly which should fix the debian package installation.

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-07**:
Many thanks @joq and @rtoris288, it is working now with the newest 0.1.2 driver.